# CSS border display issue, not working same with Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css

I have a div with dashed border, its border displays as 9 lines (dashes) in Chrome and 5 lines (dashes) in safari. Here is its CSS.

```css
.dashedLines:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 4px dashed #b7b2b3;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 84px;
        width: 108px;
        margin-left: -45px; 
    }
```

```html
    <div class="dashedLines">
    <figure class="icon">
    <i>
    <img src="{{imgs.icon_left}}" alt="Icon pencil black " />
    </i>
    </figure>
    <figure class="icon">
    <i> <img src="{{imgs.icon_right}}" alt="Icon descktop black " /> </i>
    </figure>
    </div>
```

It works like this in Safari:
[image: Safari browser]

It works like this in Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

I need dashed lines to work same as in Safari with Chrome.

Comment: Please include corresponding HTML code.....

Comment: How exactly the dashes look is mainly up to the browser ...

Comment: It obviously get differ as per browser parser! Do you need to have same number of lines?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo : Yes i need same number of lines

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get same number of lines on different browsers, then you cannot use border property. You are suppose to use some other techniques to get the desired output.

If your dashes should align horizontally then you can use below code,

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 33%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%);
background-position: bottom;
background-size: 20px 4px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

If your dashes should align vertically then you can use below code,

```
background-image: linear-gradient(black 33%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%);
background-position: right;
background-size: 20px 4px;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

```css
 .dashed-border img {
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
   background-position: bottom;
   background-size: 20px 1px;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="dashedLines">
  <figure class="icon">
    <i>
        <img src="{{imgs.icon_left}}" alt="Icon pencil black " />
        </i>
  </figure>
  <figure class="icon dashed-border">
    <i> <img src="{{imgs.icon_right}}" alt="Icon descktop black " /> </i>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Find the [fiddler](https://fiddle.jshell.net/fqvdjrvf/1/) for your reference.

Comment: do i need to add this along with my css?

Comment: check the fiddler

Comment: ya but it is not coming as i required, please help

Comment: i am unable to get this css in inspect